# Can't enable wi-fi on 14.04- all previous answers checked

Tags: 14.04, networking, lenovo

i've just installed ubuntu and there is no option for enable wi-fi.

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic


lspci -vq|grep -i wireless
```

nothing

```
lspci -vq|grep -i realtek
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

lspci -nn |grep -i net
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

My laptop is lenovo ideapad y700.